# Avoiding multiple API-auths by using sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an API that uses NTLM auth.

```
GET /api/v1/users
```

The problem is that I need to call this API several times a second and since it uses NTLM auth, the Active Directory (AD) server blocks my request once I hit a threshold, say 50 requests/s.

Is there any way to avoid multiple auth calls by using sessions/sockets, as in, authenticate once and establish a session and then keep calling the API multiple times as the connection is not closed?

Comment: Typically REST API's don't use session cookies, as it can be a security risk (unless you use CSRF or don't allow CORS). If it's your Node application calling an NTLM program that is limited to 50/s, you could try caching the results of the NTLM auth query.

Answer (score 1):

We were facing a similar issue and ended up using a custom http-agent for the request-module, i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/agentkeepalive-ntlm

This will keep the ntlm-session alive instead of creating a new one for every request.